# Finding the index of the list element whenever it is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="fullPadding">Shopping List</h1>
<p class="noTopPadding">Get it done today</p>

<input id="userInput" style="margin-left: 20px" type="text" name="shoppingItems" placeholder="Enter items">

<button id="Enter">Enter</button>

<br><br>

**<ul>
    <li>Birthday cake</li>
    <li>Candles</li>
    <li>Party hats</li>
    <li>Baloons</li>
    <li>Flowers</li>
</ul>**

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to toggle .done class on and off, Whenever I click on list element.
For this purpose I was trying to somehow extract index of the clicked list element.
I have tried many thing, but I am not getting the desired result.

I just added the event listeners to all the list element and now I am stuck

```
JS

var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

 for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
 li[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var` will solve your problem:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(let i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     console.log(event, i);
  });
}
```

Otherwise, you can:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
  (function (index) {
    li[index].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log(event, index);
    });
  })(i)
}
```

Comment: @sahil see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Other_situations